# 2D animation -- lines disappeared onto another frame

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I am trying to work on a simple 2D animation project in Blender, but when I try to draw a new line, it disappears onto another keyframe. I am trying to learn how to do that on an XP-PEN Artist 12 tablet, but accidentally pressing those buttons on the side makes it difficult to do anything. Any help?

Comment: If you’re pressing buttons on the side by mistake, anything is possible. Welcome to the twilight animation.

Comment: I would disable any buttons that you have a tendency to press accidentally. In fact, I would disable all of the express keys on any graphic tablet as a matter of course and use keyboard shortcuts exclusively, which is the workflow that Blender tends to encourage anyway, because it has so many functions and is so keyboard shortcut heavy.

Comment: How do I disable the express keys?